# Cloud Object Storage Error - Create Bucket needs Writer or higher permission

Tags: ibm-cloud-storage

I am receiving an error in creating my first storage bucket in lite plan.  It says I need a writer or higher permission.  Since I am the only owner of my IBM cloud instance I am stumped.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a new tab.
2. IBM Cloud Catalog https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog.
3. Search and select Object Storage

You've 2 option from here:

1. If the bucket somehow is created it will show an error telling that the bucket it's already created. "You can only have one instance of a Lite plan per service. To create a new instance, either delete your existing Lite plan instance or select a paid plan."

If that happens, click on the warning and you will be in the Storage instances page. Click on ' Create bucket' and then you are able to start configuring your bucket.

2. If you do not have any errors, try to do the process again.